# How to reduce MSI fan noise without dragon center

Tags: windows-10, control-panel, msi-afterburner

I bought a new MSI laptop GS75 stealth. I am getting incredibly high noise from the fans and CPU temperature as soon as the power is plugged, even at standby.

How can I decrease the strain on the CPU's and fan noise? The only way I found so far is to download the official bloat/malware from MSI ('dragon center') where fan speed can be decreased by the option 'scenario:silent', however I'd like to not be bullied by MSI into installing their garbage just for a power saver option.

[image: dragon center]

My Windows 10 "pro" Power options does not include the 'powersaving' plan, and the hardware part has mysteriously been forgotten in my UEFI BIOS...

Cheers

Comment: Does the bios have a setting for the fans?

Comment: no,no hardware part where I can change fan speed. msi click bios

Comment: then you are stuck with the msi software unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Silent Option software can do this https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/updated-2016-05-06-silent-option-fan-control-application-for-msi-laptops.255972/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1103692)

Answer (score 0):

I finally sent my PC to maintenance, and got it exchanged to a new model. This fan problem is common for the Stealth line, and the culprit part isn't available anymore.